# Powershell config to force a batch file to run within the powershell window?

Tags: powershell

I've got a powershell script that eventually passes a stack of arguments into a batch file via `invoke-expression` command.

However, on one server, when the powershell scripts executes that batch file, that batch file opens in a new window, but on the other server, the batch file executes within the powershell window.

What that means, is that I've got a sleep interval that is starting once the batch file begins executing in the new window, and thus screwing up my timings, unlike the other server, where the sleep interval doesn't begin until *after* the batch file has finished executing.

So my question is... does anybody know why the behaviours are different between the two servers, and how to get the batch file to execute in the powershell window? I'm thinking it's a configuration thing, but can't actually find anything that tells me how to make it do what I want it to do.....

Thanks!

--edit--

I'm currently just piping the line straight through like this:
`E:\Software\ibm\WebSphere\AppServer\bin\wsadmin -lang jython -username $($username) -password $($password) -f "F:\Custom\dumpAllThreads.py" $($servers)`

Previously, it was

```
$invokeString = 'E:\Software\ibm\WebSphere\AppServer\bin\wsadmin -lang jython -username $($username) -password $($password) -f "F:\Custom\dumpAllThreads.py" $($servers)'
$output = invoke-expression $invokeString
```

Both had the same behaviour.

Comment: Are you using the same version of powershell on both systems?

Comment: yes, i am. :) using $PSVersionTable.psversion, I get 2, 0, -1, -1 on both boxes.

Comment: try using `start-process` instead and use the `-nonewwindow` flag

Comment: that's a bit of a rescript (i'll need to rewrite the way that some of the arguments are passed through), but it also doesn't explain why there's a difference between the two. :(

Comment: Definitely strange. At a guess, I'd say that one of the machines has a modified association for batch files. Is there a modified registry entry in `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.bat` on one of the machines? The `OpenWithList` subkey should be empty. If the entry does appear to have been modified, you can apparently recreate it by deleting it then rebooting. As others have mentioned, `start-process` is more appropriate when marshalling external processes. Finally, can you please update your question with your `invoke-expression` code?

Comment: Added the invoke-expression. I've also checked the registry entry and both servers have the same set of key/value pairs, with both boxes having the same default value of .bat->OpenWithList of `(value not set)`. I think I'm just going to rescript to use the suggested `start-process` method.

Comment: Is it possible that the machines have different values in the [JYTHON_OPTS environment variable](http://www.jython.org/docs/using/cmdline.html)?

Answer (score 1):

> So my question is... does anybody know why the behaviours are different between the two servers

Most often I've seen this sort of thing related to how a scripts is called.  If the same user is logged on multiple times on the same server (i.e., console and RDP) then the window might appear in a different session.  Similarly, if the script runs as a scheduled task and the user that runs the task isn't the user logged on, the window will never be visible.  If the same user is logged on, it might be visible.

> how to get the batch file to execute in the powershell window?

You could try `Start-Process` with `-NoNewWindow`, as @Paul mentions.

However....

> What that means, is that I've got a sleep interval that is starting once the batch file begins executing in the new window, and thus screwing up my timings, unlike the other server, where the sleep interval doesn't begin until after the batch file has finished executing.

It sounds like your *actual* problem is that your code has a race condition.  You should fix the actual problem.  Use `Start-Process` with the `-Wait` parameter, or use the jobs system in PowerShell.

Comment: I'm running the exact same script through powershell, in the exact same manner, on two servers that I've RDP-ed into with the same user. Intent is to run the same activity 3 times, with a sleep interval in between. i.e. "get me the current stats, wait 30 seconds. get stats again. wait 30 seconds, get stats again." If I don't have a choice - and its looking more and more like that - then I'll rescript and hope that works. it's relatively straight forward to change. This is really more me being curious about why the same script + trigger on the two servers leads to two differing behaviours.